# Ejercicio de bucles for anidados en python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, ciclos

He estado practicando con unos ejercicio sencillos de Python 3x que conseguí en la web, tratan sobre bucles for anidados que dibujan figuras geométricas, sin embargo, hay uno al cual no le consigo solución por más intentos que he hecho. El ejercicio dice así:

> Escriba un programa que pida la anchura y altura de un rectángulo y lo
>   dibuje con caracteres asterisco "*" y guión "-":

Anchura: **6**
Altura: **4**

*La salida debería ser mas o menos así, un rectángulo de asteriscos relleno con guiones:*

"* * * * * *
 * - - - - *
 * - - - - *
 * * * * * *"

*Sin embargo mi código me da ésta salida:*

"* * * * -
* * * *  -
* * * * -
* * * * -
* * * * -
* * * * -
* * * * -"

Aquí coloco mi código en python 3.6:

```
alto=int(input("Introduce la altura:"))
largo=int(input("ahora la longitud:"))
for a in range(alto):
    for l in range(1,largo):
        print("*",end=" ")
    print("-")
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te paso una posible solución

```
alto=int(input("Introduce la altura:"))
largo=int(input("ahora la anchura:"))
for a in range(alto):
    if (a is not 0) and (a != alto - 1):
       for l in range(largo):
           if (l is not 0) and (l != largo - 1):
              print("-", end='')
           else:
               print("*",end="")
    else:
      for l in range(largo):
          print("*",end="")
    print('')
```

Answer (score 4):

Te paso otra posible respuesta usando una variable de nombre "dibujo"

```
dibujo=''
anchura=20
altura=20


for i in range(0,altura):


    for j in range(0,anchura):
        if i ==0 or i == altura-1:
            dibujo+='*'
        elif j ==0 or j==anchura-1:
            dibujo+='*'
        else:
            dibujo +='-'
    dibujo+='\n'



print ("\n"*2)
print (dibujo)
```

Answer (score 3):

Reemplace los guiones por espacios:

```
h=int(input("Introduce la altura del rectangulo: "))
a=int(input("Introduce la anchura del rectangulo: "))

for x in range(1):
    print("*"*a)

    for y in range(h-2):
        g=a-2#numero de guiones
        print("*"+(" "*g)+"*")

    print("*"*a)
```

Comment: Muy buena solución, pero sobra el for x in range(1), no hace nada

Answer (score 3):

A mi me sirve con este:

```
ancho=int(input("dame el ancho de tu figura"))
alto=int(input("dame el alto de tu figura"))

for i in range(0,alto):
    for j in range(0,ancho):
        if j==0 or j==ancho-1:
            print("*",end="")
        elif  (i==0 or i==alto-1):
            print("*",end="")
        else:
            print("-",end="")
    print("")
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra posible solución:

```
h = int(input("Altura: "))
a = int(input("Ancho: "))

for i in range(h):
    if i == 0:
        print("*"*a)
    for j in range(a):
        if j == a-1:
            print("*","-" * (a-2),"*")
    if i == h-1:
        print("*"*a)
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
print("*****DIBUJAR CUADRADO/RECTANGULO*****\n")
alt = int(input("Altura de la figura : "))
anc = int(input("Ancho de la figura  : "))
print()
i = 0
print("*"*anc)
while i != (alt-2):
    print("*"+"-"*(anc-2)+"*")
    i +=1
print("*"*anc)
```

Comment: Considera explicar tu código, pues una respuesta conteniendo sólo código se considera de baja calidad

Answer (score 1):

```
# dibuja rectangulo:
altura=int(input("inserte la altura del rectangulo: "))
ancho=int(input("inserte el ancho del rectangulo: "))

for i in range(altura):
    for j in range(ancho):
        if i==0 or i==altura-1:
            print("*",end="")
    
        else:
            if j==0 or j==ancho-1:
                print("*",end="")
            else:
                print("-",end="")
    print("")
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Buenos días Jorgesys. Ya había leído el apartado "como responder" y lo he vuelto a leer pero no veo en que punto estoy incumpliendo la política de la página. ¿Podríais concretar más para no seguir cometiendo el mismo error en futuras respuestas? Gracias, un saludo

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que publica el usuario, como resuelve el problema? , tu publicación es únicamente código y no indica al usuario como resuelve su problema.